# What regex to use in this case

Tags: regex

Correct code:

```
"key1=val1;key2=val2;key3=val3"    -- Correct as each pair is having ";" at the end except the last pair
```

Incorrect code:

```
"key1=val1;key2=val2; key3=val3;"    -- Invalid as last pair is having ";" at the end
"key1=val1;;;key2=val2;;;key3=val3"   -- Invalid as there are multiple ";" in the middle
```

I got the regex below from some old link in stackoverflow, but it is not working in the above case:

```
^(?:\s*\w+\s*=\s*[^;]*;)+$
```

Comment: I got something. can any one verify
(^(?:\\s*\\w+\\s*=\\s*[^;]*;)+).*[^;]$

Comment: Can the key or the value contain `=` or `;` and if yes, how are they escaped?

Answer (score 2):

You might use

```
^\w+\s*=\s*\w+(?:;\s*\w+\s*=\s*\w+)*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\w+\s*=\s*\w+` Match 1+ word chars, `=` and 1+ word chars with optional whitespace chars
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `;\s*\w+\s*=\s*\w+` Match `;` and the same patter as mentioned above
- `)*` Close the group and repeat 0+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9GnYrP/1)

With the doubled backslashes

```
^\\w+\\s*=\\s*\\w+(?:;\\s*\\w+\\s*=\\s*\\w+)*$
```

Comment: No .. This wont work for the below
key1=val1;key2=val2  key3=val3

It should not pick the above as there is a missing ; after key2=val2

Comment: @user10278830 It does not match that https://regex101.com/r/QPtDfB/1

Answer (score 1):

Also, a shorter one:

```
^(?:\s*\w+\s*=\s*\w+(?:;(?!\s*$)|\s*$))+\s*$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/vPKHoW/1)

**Explanation**

```
                         EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    =                        '='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ;                        ';'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                                 (0 or more times (matching the most
                                 amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $                        before an optional \n, and the end
                                 of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                               (0 or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                               the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
.*\w;\w.*\w;\w.*[^;]$
```

Test [here](https://regex101.com/r/00M0yM/2)

Explanation:

- .* --> matches any character
- \w --> matches any word character
- [^;]$ --> Will exclude any line ending with ;

Comment: `[\w]` --> `\w`. Also, no need for a dot-star-soup here.

Comment: I am using .* to select rest of the characters in the line. Without that, I doubt if it will work

Answer (score 0):

I find things like this much easier without regex. For eample with JavaScript:

```
function isValid(string) {
  return string.split(/;/).map(e => e.split(/=/)).every(e => e.length === 2);
}
```